# unnest all columns from a given table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, which was loaded dynamically from an external job. This table has a changing number of coulmns from time to time.
I want to `unnest` all the columns with the coulmn name as 'Key' and the value as 'Value':

```
SELECT
   unnest(array[(select array_agg( column_name::text )from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName')]) AS "Keys",
   unnest(array[tableName.col1, tablename.col2, ...]) AS "Values"
FROM tableName ;
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I need something to replace the second `unnest` Statement, because I don't know the names of the columns.

I thought I just use `unnest(array[tableName.*]) as "Values"`but that does not work.

Any ideas welcome.

Example:

```
create table mytest ( col_1 varchar(30), col_2 varchar(30));
insert into mytest values ('a1','b1');
insert into mytest values ('a2','b2');
insert into mytest values ('a3','b3');
SELECT
   unnest(array[(select array_agg( column_name::text )from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'mytest')]) AS "Key",
   unnest(array[mytest.col_1, mytest.col_2]) AS "Value"
FROM mytest ;
```

Results in:

```
"Key"   "Value"
col_1   a1
col_2   b1
col_1   a2
col_2   b2
col_1   a3
col_2   b3
```

which is fine.
But when I get a table of unknown numbers of columns I need something to put into the second unnest statement (`unnest(array[tableName.col1, tablename.col2, ...])`) so I thought somethng like `tablename.*` instead of `tableName.col1, tablename.col2`.

Comment: I'm sure you know it and you can't do it because of external constraints, but it would be so much better to modelize your data correctly... Remember Pike's 5th rule...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON functions to do that for you:

```
select x.*
from mytest, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(mytest)) as x("key",value);
```

With your sample data, this returns:

```
key   | value
------+------
col_1 | a1   
col_2 | b1   
col_1 | a2   
col_2 | b2   
col_1 | a3   
col_2 | b3
```

`to_jsonb(mytest)` converts the whole row into a JSON value using the column names as keys and `jsonb_each_text()` is the unnesting of that JSON value.

Online example: https://rextester.com/DSNOIU44927