# Reshape table by converting columns to rows

Tags: postgresql

### The problem

I'm trying to reshape a table with many columns. I'm trying to do it independently of the specific table, so I'm trying to do it for any table.

Let's use a very simple table `foo`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (id int, a text, b text, c text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'ant', 'cat', 'chimp'), (2, 'grape', 'mint', 'basil');
```

```
select * from foo;

| id|  a  |  b |  c  |
|---|-----|----|-----|
|  1| ant | cat|chimp|
|  2|grape|mint|basil|
```

I want to transform the column `a`, `b` and `c` to rows.

This query works (for this specific table):

```sql
SELECT id,
       unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c']) AS colname,
       unnest(array[a, b, c]) AS colvalue
FROM foo;

|id|colname|colvalue|
|--|-------|--------|
| 1|  a    |  ant   |
| 1|  b    |  cat   |
| 1|  c    | chimp  |
| 2|  a    | grape  |
| 2|  b    | mint   |
| 2|  c    | basil  |
```

But I want to make it generic for any table with lots of columns.

### What I've already done

To get all the columns I want to transform in rows, I can use:

```sql
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name   = 'foo' and column_name ~ '^[a-z]$';
```

So using the previous query, I can do the following:

```sql
WITH tablecolumns AS (SELECT array_agg( column_name ) as cols FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'foo' and column_name ~ '^[a-z]$') 
select id, 
       unnest( tablecolumns.cols ) AS colname,
       unnest( array[a, b, c] ) AS colvalue
FROM foo, tablecolumns;
```

But I'm not able to replace `array[a, b, c]` with something dynamic. If I use:

```sql
WITH tablecolumns AS (SELECT array_agg( column_name ) as cols FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'foo' and column_name ~ '^[a-z]$') 
select id, 
       unnest( tablecolumns.cols ) AS colname,
       unnest( tablecolumns.cols ) AS colvalue
FROM foo, tablecolumns;
```

the result is not the values of the columns, but just the name of the columns.

### Question

How can I `unnest` the values of the columns?

Comment: Hum... My question seems quite similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230873/unnest-all-columns-from-a-given-table

Comment: I want to repeat some columns from the original table (like the id), so using `to_jsonb` on the entire row might not be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have the column names being evaluated as columns, as pointed out in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800367/select-columns-with-particular-column-names-in-postgresql

The way to do it, is using `to_jsonb`, as suggested in [unnest all columns from a given table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230873/unnest-all-columns-from-a-given-table), like:

```sql
select foo.id, x.*
from foo, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(foo)) as x(colname,colvalue)
where x.colname ~ '^[a-z]$';
```

In my specific case, I was trying to convert all data related to Corona Virus. The original data is available at: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv. I've imported it as table `covid`.

It has many columns named after the date, like: `'1/22/20','1/23/20','1/24/20','1/25/20','1/26/20', ...`. The first columns are related with the location, so I want to keep them in the reshaped table.

The final query I'm using is:

```sql
select id, geom, "province/state" , "country/region", to_date( reportdate, 'MM/DD/YY'), nofcases
from covid, jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(covid)) as x(reportdate,nofcases)
where x.reportdate ~ '[0-9]+'
order by 5;
```